# for r, when; π'=L/D=π sin (α/2)/(α/2)=π sin (r/R)/(r/R)

Tags: trigonometry

how may I rearrange the following equation in order to solve for

i) $\alpha$,

ii) $r$, 
when $\pi'=L/D = \pi  \sin (\alpha/2)/(\alpha/2) =\pi \sin (r/R)/(r/R)$

Many thanks to those who wish to reply seriously !,
Peter

Comment: you can't solve analytically for either in terms of the usual functions (powers and roots, sin, cos, ln or exp).

Comment: Hi , , let's do some simple geometry: Imagine a sphere of radius R. We define a circle on the surface of that sphere as we would define a circle anywhere: a geometrical shape consisting of points equally distant from a selected point. that radius r is measured along the curved line on the surface of the sphere from a point also on that surface. Now, if we actually calculate the circumference of one of the circles of radius r, it would be L=2πR sin(r/R)=2πR sin(α/2), where α is the flat angle from the center of the sphere to the circle on its surface, varying ratio circumference to diameter

Comment: π'=L/D=π sin (α/2)/(α/2)=π sin (r/R)/(r/R)

Comment: full article here:https://physics.illinois.edu/news/article/10665

Comment: Not sure what that adds to your question. You still cannot solve for $\alpha$ or $r$ analytically.